# exponent of a finite group divides order of the group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $m\in\Bbb N$ be the exponent of a finite group $G\ $  ($|G|=n$). It' the smallest integer such that $g^m=e_G\ \forall g\in G$

Proving that $m\mid |G|$ is the same as proving that the least common multiple of the orders of the elements of $G$ divides the order of the group once you realize the exponent is the LCM of $o(g)$ for $g\in G$.

But how to conclude the proof?

I tried to reason with $q_i\cdot o(g_i)=|G|\ \forall i\in[n]$ but it doesn't seem to lead me enywhere

Comment: Have you thought of showing that the prime-power divisors of the exponent divide the order of the group?

Comment: @ancientmathematician no, I'll try that

Answer (score 1):

Some hints: By Lagrange's Theorem, the order of every element of a finite group must divide the order of the group. In addition it implies that $a^{|G|}=e$ for all $a\in G$.